# Getting error while starting presto as $ sudo bin/launcher run

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04, presto

### When I'm starting presto as this, it was started but

```
sys2079@sys2079:~/Music/presto-server-0.149$ sudo bin/launcher start
```

### Started as 10672

After that i tried to lunch the presto then I'm getting error like this

---

```
sys2079@sys2079:~/presto-server-0.149$ sudo bin/launcher run
```

> Unrecognized VM option 'G1HeapRegionSize = 32M'
>   Did you mean 'G1HeapRegionSize='?
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

---

WHAT I HAVE TO DO ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the RAM in your /etc/config.properties file

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://<your IP or *Localhost*>:8080
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `jvm.config` file inside presto. You should write your JVM option as: `G1HeapRegionSize=32M` instead of `G1HeapRegionSize = 32M`